# What will happen if I enter a word when required to enter an int?

Tags: c++

I have a question. Suppose the code is as followed:

```
    int a;
    cin>>a;
```

What will happen if I enter a word instead of an integer? What value will be given to `a`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .... Did you try it and see?

Comment: if you are worried about that simply input everything as a string and then convert it to desired type.

Comment: @KyleStrand  Hi, I have tried and the result is 0. And I want to know more detailed mechanism behind the result ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the result of the read operation before using the value that is being read.  The `>>` operator returns a reference to the stream being read from, and the stream contains state information to indicate whether the last operation succeeded or failed.  If failed, the value of the variable being read is indeterminate, so don't use it.

Try this:

```
int a;
if (cin >> a) // <-- same as: if (!cin.operator>>(a).fail())
{
    // read successful, use the int as needed...
}
else
{
    // read failed, do not use the int...
}
```

Comment: correct, you just forgot to give an answer to the question

Comment: @0d0a: I did answer the "what will happen" question - `>>` will fail. I did not answer the "what value will be given" question.  I have added that now.

Answer (score 1):

When the user input can't be converted to the type of the variable, cin >> leaves the variable's value untouched. You're seeing what the variable looks like uninitialized, which is zero. So when you enter a word instead of an integer, value of variable is untouched and remains uninitialized.

Comment: Local variables that are POD types are not initialized. The fact that it is zero is random behavior. It will be whatever data was already occupying the stack memory that the variable is using.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem.

In C++, a `WORD` is typically a subset of `int`.

So the complete `WORD` valuerange is easily represented as an `int`

Just have a look here:

[WORD datatype in windows environments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (it is just a two byte value here, `int` in comparison is 4 bytes wide in most cases)

And of course:
[Word size in linux](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch19lev1sec2)

Of course, this answer is somewhat tongue-in-cheek